# How to check if a string is made up of integers in PHP

Tags: php

I am writing php code to validate some data entered by the user, one of them is an integer, I used `$_REQUEST["age"]` to get it, when I'm checking if this value is integer with `gettype($_REQUEST["age"] == "integer"` and `is_int($_REQUEST["age"])` both give me false, but when I use `is_numeric($_REQUEST["age"])` is gives me true. I want to check if the value of the parameter is an integer or not, am I using the first 2 functions correctly or am I missing something?

Thakns

NOTE: I tried to output `gettype($_REQUEST["age"])` it gives me `string`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short version:**

Use `ctype_digit($_REQUEST['age'])`

**Long version:**

Your problem, as you've found when you use `gettype`, is that `$_REQUEST` returns a *string*.  Even if that string is an integer *semantically*, like `16`, it would still be a string-type and not an integer-type variable.  You're getting different results from the two tests because they test different things:

- `is_numeric` tests whether a string contains an "optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and optional exponential part" according to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).  In your case, the string does only contain digits, so the test returns `True`.
- `is_int` tests whether the variable's type is an integer - which it won't be, because it's being returned by `$_REQUEST`.

That's why `is_numeric` returns `True` while `is_int` returns `False`: the string only contains numbers (and so "is numeric") but still technically has a string type, not an integer type (and so "isn't an int").  Of course, `is_numeric` isn't sufficient for integer testing, because it will return `True` if the string has a decimal or uses scientific notation, i.e. is numeric but not an integer.

To test if the `$_REQUEST` is an integer, regardless of technical type, you can test whether all the characters in the string are digits (and thus the string as a whole is an integer).  For this you can use [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php):

```
ctype_digit($_REQUEST['age'])
```

This will return `True` for `16` but not for `16.5` or `16e0` - weeding out the integers from the numeric non-integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
     if(intval($_REQUEST["age"]) > 0):
        echo 'Ineger';
     else:
        echo 'something else';
     endif;
?>
```

Comment: `intval` computes the integer value, it doesn't test it.  If `$_REQUEST["age"]` is a positive, non-integer decimal like 4.2, this will print "Integer".  It will also not catch negative numbers, which can still be integers.